# How to go through directories to get a specific file from each directory and open that file in each directory and do some process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a path which have many directories. I need to go through each directory and get a specific file **"file.log.gz"** from it and read the file and do some process.

This is my current attempt:

```
import os
import sys
import gzip
infile = sys.argv[1]
directory = ("%s/NEW_FOLDER" % infile)

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        if "file.log.gz" in file:
            with gzip.open(os.path.join(root, file)) as fin:
                new = False
                for line in fin:
                    if "CODE" in line.decode('utf-8'):
                        print("string is present")
                        found = True
                        exit()
                    else:
                        print("string is not present")
```

what i need is to go through each directories inside `NEW_FOLDER` and get `file.log.gz`. and do the following process for file.log.gz in each directory.

with the current code i get `file.log.gz` inside each directory but i'm not able to do rest of the process that is opening file.log.gz in each directory and do the rest process.

**Expected Output:**

```
/NEW_FOLDER/dir1/file.log.gz
string is present
/NEW_FOLDER/dir2/file.log.gz
string is present
/NEW_FOLDER/dir3/file.log.gz
string is not present
```

Comment: so you have confirmed, by printing "files", you are able to find ALL the log.gz files correct? Your sole problem is unzipping of the file and reading its contents correct?

Comment: yes i have confirmed that im able to get file.log.gz from each directory. What i need is to get the output in expected form.

Comment: with gzip.open("file.log.gz") as fin:   << it's this part, you are opening this same string all the time. instead you should be doing this >> with gzip.open(file) as fin:

Comment: I tried to do this way but it was showing no such file or directory: "file.log.gz "

Comment: let me write it in the answers below.

Comment: I have edited this >> with  gzip.open("file.log.gz") as fin: by this >> with gzip.open(os.path.join(root, file)) as fin:  now it's working.

Comment: but now only problem is if "CODE" is present in file it will exit there and won't go for checking files in next directory.

Comment: yes I'm glad you found it out. you can always do lots of printing to determine the source of issue. answer written below

Comment: you have a exit() function there. you need to remove it if you don't intend to exit on the first finding of "CODE". Maybe your intention is to stop searching the file. in that case using "break" is enough. Also try not to edit your initial code in question, or else others that visit this page will not learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `os.walk()`. You need to merge the root directory with the filename. You will notice it if you `print (file)` and see what the values you are getting.

Try print this out. You suppose to pass the entire directory to open and not just the file name.

```
for file in files:
  print(os.path.join(root, file))
```